# Compute $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 - 2\cos(y) + 2}{y^2 - 2\cos(x) + 2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Does the limit $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left( \frac{x^2 - 2\cos(y) + 2}{y^2 - 2\cos(x) + 2} \right) $$ exist?

I think it does and it's equal to $1$, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried to use Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(y)$, but it doesn't help me to compute the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, since $\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^4)$ as $t\to 0$, we have that
$$\frac{x^2 - 2\cos(y) + 2}{y^2 - 2\cos(x) + 2}=\frac{x^2 - 2+y^2+O(y^4) + 2}{y^2 - 2+x^2+O(x^4) + 2}=\frac{r^2+O(y^4)}{r^2+O(x^4)}=\frac{1+\frac{O(y^4)}{r^2}}{1+\frac{O(x^4)}{r^2}}$$
where $r^2=x^2+y^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get after using Taylor expansion. Does that mean that the limit does not exist?

Comment: @Jack: So what happens if you factor $r^2$ out of numerator and denominator?

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot about the common factor, now I see that it exists and it's equal to 1, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jack Well done!